# Levelplot not plotted correctly, values not overlaid on grids

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I have gridded data on a pollutant. Each grid is denoted by its left most latitude and longitude. I would like to see how the level of this pollutant varies across grids. For this, I have made a level plot. My code shown below runs fine but the only trouble is that the plotted pollutant does not overlay the grids made using abline. Although I have specified the limit cutoffs for x and y, the values are plotted ahead of these cutoffs.

```
    library(lattice)
    library(maptools)
    imap = readShapeSpatial("IND_adm3")
    pdf("trial2.pdf",width=11, height=8)
    levelplot(surface_aod~longitude+latitude,data=s.data,
                  panel = function(...){
                  panel.levelplot(...)
                  panel.abline(v=(71:88),col="dark red")              
                             panel.abline(h=(17:31),col="dark red")    
                   sp.polygons(imap)         
                     }, 
   col.regions = heat.colors(100),aspect="iso", region=TRUE,scales=list(x=list(at=seq(from=71,to=88, by=1)), y=list(at=seq(from=17,to=31,   by=1)),cex=.7, alternating=3),xlim=c(70,90), ylim=c(16,32))
   dev.off()
```

Here is a snippet of my data.

```
 dput(head(s.data))
 structure(list(latitude = c(17L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L), longitude = c(80L, 
 82L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 75L), surface_aod = c(0.2652681, 0.0040855, 
 0.2032517, 0.0929442, 0.1194997, 0.3600747)), .Names = c("latitude", 
 "longitude", "surface_aod"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I get the values to overlay on the grids? Thanks.

Comment: Please comment if I interpreted your question wrong. Are you saying that gridded values don't show at all because they are overlapped (what I understood) or that they are centered on your x,y coords and so don't coincide with your abline grid as expected, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpretation 1) (If the problem is that you don't see your gridded values) :
I think you just need to change the order in your panel function:

```
panel = function(...){
                 # panel.levelplot(...) # insead of marking up 
                 # on top of the plotted values
                   sp.polygons(imap) 
                   panel.levelplot(...)   
                   panel.abline(v=(71:88),col="dark red")              
                   panel.abline(h=(17:31),col="dark red")         
                     }
```

If you don't want the grid lines over your vales, then move `panel.levelplot(...)` to the end... you get the idea.

Interpretation 2) (if the problem is that the gridded values are centered rather than aligned to your longlat in the lower left corner:

```
# shift the long lat to the cell center. In this case, 
# the centroid is convenetly, .5 up
# and .5 over, so you can do it in-line:
levelplot(surface_aod~I(longitude+.5)+I(latitude+.5),data=s.data,
        panel = function(...){
            panel.levelplot(...)
            panel.abline(v=(71:88),col="dark red")              
            panel.abline(h=(17:31),col="dark red")    
            #sp.polygons(imap)         
        }, 
        col.regions = heat.colors(100),
        aspect="iso", 
        region=TRUE,
        scales=list(x=list(at=seq(from=71,to=88, by=1)), 
                y=list(at=seq(from=17,to=31, by=1)),
                cex=.7, 
                alternating=3),
        xlim=c(70,90), 
        ylim=c(16,32)
)
```

Again, I'm not sure which of these you were asking, so please comment if neither is what you were looking for.

Comment: I had to center my data. I should have been able to spot this. Thanks Tim